# Can we Use php script in Google Tag Manager

Tags: php, google-tag-manager

Just wondering if a php code could be executed via Google Tag manager?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No. The Google Tag Manager inserts client-side Javascript. PHP requires a server that is configured for PHP. Inserting a PHP script via GTM would just output the raw PHP code to the browser, it would not execute the code.

If you want to include the results of a PHP Script you would have to run the script on your own server and fetch the results via Javascript as suggested in UncleRicos answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Custom Events in Triggers here: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961?hl=en&ref_topic=3441647&vid=1-635797415927700239-1991783559

You can specify a javascript event that would be called upon a trigger being executed, which in turn could call a routine via ajax (which could be PHP or anything).